# Get the immediate values from the adjacent columns based on the value of another column

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am trying to get the immediate next adjacent column values based on the values of another column. I tried by adding serial numbers and VLOOKUP() but I'm getting some mismatches.

The data is in columns A to C and the output required should be in column D.

Based on the column C, if the value is NA, I need the date from the next row for the same ID. If the next ID is different, I need the same date in column D.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the function IF(), you can nest them to get the result you want. See formula for cell D2:

```
=IF(C2="NA",IF(B3=B2,A3,A2),"")
```